# How to set up a new GIS large format Plotter?

Tags: printing, colors

We have a new HP t1300 Plotter and of course the drivers offer new methods regarding the following settings:

Standard-RGB Source profile

- sRGB IE61966-2.1
- Adobe RGB (1998)
- Apple RGB
- ColorMatch RGB

Standard-CMYK Source profile

- HP Plus Technology
- US Web Coated (SWOP) v2
- Euroscale
- Japan Web Coated
- etc,etc etc about 20 more

Rendering Intent options

- Perceptual
- Absolute colormetric
- Relative colormetric
- Saturation

HP Professional PANTONE

-Emulation

Image Color Matching offers another 4 choices:

-ICM Deaktivated
 -ICM from Host
 -ICM From Printer
 -ICM from print calibration

So I could spend the next two weeks analysing the documentation and testing each combination of settings to see what happens but I don´t have the time. We need a production plotter ASAP and hence this thread to see if anyone can offer any basic advice.

Are there any Plotter professionals who can tell me what area I need to concentrate on and maybe also what to ignore. My objective is to simply have a plotter that plots exactly what I see on my RGB monitor. It would be a weight off my mind to know that what I see is what I get!

Comment: This looks to me like a question for [su].  It mentions GIS in the title but really your plotter could be being used for hardcopy from many other types of software.

Comment: GIS could also be replaces with high-resolution images; can it be migrated?